# xsd:SimpleType: How to restrict attribute to specific values and regex values

Tags: regex, xsd, restrictions

I have an attribute that can be any string, but if it has starting and ending brackets `"^[.*]$"` - it must be only one of the following specific values:

```
"[EVENT]"
```

and

```
"[PROTOCOL]"
```

So, `"[EVENT]"`, `"[PROTOCOL]"`, `"SomeString"` - are correct, but `"[SomeString]"` - isn't.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Should `[SomeString` without the closing bracket be valid?

Comment: Actually, no. It shouldn't be valid.

Comment: And, I'm guessing that `SomeString]` without the opening bracket should also be invalid then, right?  [My answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26049756/290085) accepts and rejects the cases as listed in your question, plus rejects `"[SomeString"` and `"SomeString]"` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like @Burkart's use of separate `xs:pattern` elements better (+1), but I had this pending while awaiting clarification in comments (`"[SomeString"` without a closing bracket should be invalid), so I'll post it anyway in case anyone might find it useful.  Read the regular expression as ***EVENT or PROTOCOL within brackets or any string that doesn't start or end with a bracket.***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="attr">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="\[(EVENT|PROTOCOL)\]|[^\[].*[^\]]"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Good idea! 

What about more complex case: actually I have not 2, but 10 "bracketed" variables ([EVENT], [PROTOCOL], [SESSION], etc...)

Valid cases are:
1. Any string without brackets
2. Mentioned 10 "bracketed" variables
3. Any bracketed variable(s) concatenated with regular strings, for example: My[EVENT]_for_[PROTOCOL]@google.com

Non-valid cases:
1. Any string inside brackets, except 10 predefined
2. The same with concatenations
3. Strings with only opening or closing bracket

To be short - inside brackets can be only predefined variables

Comment: @lyes, I'd suggest you post a new question.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I posted new question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26059526/xsdsimpletype-how-to-restrict-attribute-to-list-of-specific-values-with-concat

Answer (score 3):

Use an `xs:simpleType` and regular expressions to restrict the base `xs:string` type. You can have more than one `xs:pattern` to keep the alternative patterns simple. The element has to match one of the patterns or validation will fail. Since the patterns are regular expressions, special characters like "[" and "]" have to be escaped when used as literals.

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="elem" type="myElemType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="myElemType">
    <xs:attribute name="attrib" type="myAttribType"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:simpleType name="myAttribType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="\[EVENT\]"/><!-- "[EVENT]": okay -->
      <xs:pattern value="\[PROTOCOL\]"/><!-- "[PROTOCOL]": okay -->
      <xs:pattern value="[^\[].*"/><!-- Starts with anything but "[": okay -->
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

XML:

```
<root>
  <elem attrib="[EVENT]"/>
  <elem attrib="[PROTOCOL]"/>
  <elem attrib="SomeString"/>
  <elem attrib="SomeString]"/>
  <elem attrib="   [SomeString]   "/>
  <!-- All the above are okay; the ones below fail validation -->
  <elem attrib="[SomeString]"/>
  <elem attrib="[SomeString"/>
</root>
```

Modify the regular expressions to your heart's content, e.g., to fail the example with leading and/or trailing spaces.

*Edited* to reflect OP's comment that "[SomeString" should also be invalid.

Comment: @lyres: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted by clicking the green check mark.