# xsd:SimpleType: How to restrict attribute to list of specific values with concatenations

Tags: xml, regex, xsd

I have 10 "bracketed" variables ("[EVENT]", "[PROTOCOL]", "[SESSION]", etc...) 
I need to restrict an attribute.
Valid cases are:

1. Any string without brackets
2. Mentioned 10 "bracketed" variables
3. Any bracketed variable(s) concatenated with regular strings, for example:
   My[EVENT]*for*[PROTOCOL]@google.com
4. Empty string

Non-valid cases:

1. Any string inside brackets, except 10 predefined
2. The same with concatenations
3. Strings with only opening or closing bracket

To be short - inside brackets only predefined variables are allowed and they can be concatenated with any string.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the regular expression as follows:  ***The concatenation of one or more substrings containing no brackets except for those surrounding EVENT, PROTOCOL, or SESSION.***  This is trivially extended to additional acceptable bracketed variables.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="attr">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[^\[\]]*"/>
            <xs:pattern value="([^\[\]]*\[(EVENT|PROTOCOL|SESSION)\][^\[\]]*)+"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Unfortunately this pattern doesn't match regular strings without brackets (my first valid case)

Comment: Wow! You are fast! There is only one case remained - empty string should be treated as valid too (I forgot to include it to my original question).

Comment: Empty string is now supported too.  (You can see that was as easy as changing from `+` to `*` on the non-bracket string case.)